Notification preview text consists of app name twice
Sometimes when I receive notifications from the Spark email app or Google Maps, the notification text will be the app name repeated twice. For example, notifications from Spark will read "Spark Spark" and Google Maps notifications will be "Maps Maps". If I swipe down to open the notification center, notifications from Spark will display the email message contents as expected.
I have the settings in Spark set to always show the email contents. Notifications from other apps like Discord display the message content on full. This occurs while phone is unlocked and in active use.
I am using an Asus Zenfone 8 running system 33.0210.0210.332, Android version 13.
Why are some of my notifications the app name twice? How do I get the correct notification text to always appear?



If it's not private, could you also state the content of the Google Maps notification?

@AndrewT. I was using Google Maps to get directions to a location at the time.

If that's the case, then I have a hunch it's a custom notification, not a standard textual notification. However, I don't have a device to check or confirm...
